# How to get Date pattern from Timezone of Locale in Java

Tags: java, date, timezone, locale

I have a timezone, and Locale of the user. Now I want to get the date pattern.

For example: User's timezone PST and Locale US and the pattern I expect is "MM/dd/yyyy" and if the user's timezone is IST and Locale India, then pattern I expect is "dd/MM/yyyy"

How to get this?

Note: I want to get the pattern not the actual date so that I can use this in some other place.

Comment: why not use the locale in "this other place", instead of just the pattern?

Comment: Hi Petal Ivanov, actually, I want to pass the pattern to Javascript so I cannot use the Locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really do you need the TZ for date pattern? The usual way is having the data pattern in the localized properties file for a locale (or locale_country). I think it is enough.

Comment: I do not need TZ for date pattern. but in general, thats what I have in my hand (user's timezone details).

"The usual way is having the data pattern in the localized properties file for a locale (or locale_country)" - does this mean, the best way is to maintain date pattern at country level (and save it either in database or file system)?

Comment: Yes, it is. The TZ cannot be retrieved from http request, so you only know the locale/country of the client. The other way is to ask user the TZ ans save it in database with the rest of user information.

Answer (score 3):

The logic translating `Locale` to date/time formats is burried in `java.text.SimpleDateFormat#SimpleDateFormat` constructor, precisely in `sun.util.resources.LocaleData#getDateFormatData`. This method provides `ResourceBundle` which is then queried for particular pattern depending on which style was chosen.

In other words - unfortunately JDK doesn't seems to provide an API/SPI to access raw formats. My advice is to use the `Locale` all along and pass it to formatting/parsing methods.

Comment: +1 for the passing locale to your own formatting methods, the ultimate flexible solution

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The modern solution use the *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible legacy classes such as `SimpleDateFormat`. Specifically replaced by [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

### Skip the formatting pattern, let *java.time* localize automatically

You asked:

> I have a timezone, and Locale of the user. Now I want to get the date pattern.

There is no need to actually obtain the formatting pattern used by a particular locale.

The `.ofLocalized…` methods on [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) return a formatter object that can  automatically localize the text representing the the date-time object’s value. So you don't need to see the pattern, just ask for generated textual result.

The [`FormatStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) object controls how long or abbreviated the text. The [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) determines the human language and cultural norms to use in localizing.

```java
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ; 

Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;
DateTimeFormatter f = 
        DateTimeFormatter
        .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )
        .withLocale( locale ) 
;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

Dump to console.

```java
System.out.println( zdt.toInstant().toString() ) ;  // Adjust to UTC.
System.out.println( zdt.toString() ) ;              // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format extended wisely to append the name of the time zone in square brackets.
System.out.println( output ) ;                      // Automatically formatted content.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/8gyeLS).

> 2020-07-13T23:26:40.554180Z

> 2020-07-14T08:26:40.554180+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]

> mardi 14 juillet 2020 à 08 h 26 min 40 s heure normale du Japon

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the [static `getInstance` methods](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) on DateFormat. They take an integer constant for style (short, long, etc.), and optionally a different Locale (instead of the JVM's default).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Interface Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

the k will be Locale
the v will be a string with the date pattern

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Joda Time (and why wouldn't you if you have any choice? It nearly got bundled into JDK 1.7) you could do something like this:

```
String patternForStyleAndLocale = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.patternForStyle("S-", locale);
```

Which unfortunately only gives a two digit year. One work around for that would be:

```
if (!org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.contains(patternForStyleAndLocale, "yyyy"))
{
    // The default Joda pattern only has a two digit year for US and Europe, China etc - but we want four digit years
    patternForStyleAndLocale = StringUtils.replace(patternForStyleAndLocale, "yy", "yyyy");
}
```

And you could consider caching them in a `ConcurrentHashMap<Locale, String>`.

The nice thing about getting a numeric date as a pre-localised pattern like this is that it doesn't require any further localisation later, as it would do if you were using a pattern such as:

```
"dd MMM yyyy" // UK: "25 Dec 2010" FRANCE: "25 déc. 2010" etc..
```

*However...* I just noticed from your later comment that you want to pass the pattern to JavaScript - that might get very difficult since JS uses different pattern formatting to Java (ISO date for instance is `"yyyy-MM-dd"` in Java and `"yy-mm-dd"` in JS). I've not tried solving that one but I'd probably use a some string mapping in the JS or Java to simply map from Java patterns to JS. You'd have to know each of the patterns you might encounter for each of the languages in advance of course.